# Pandas to csv method in append mode with dataframes with different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large number of csv files that I need to merge into a single one. I can't make a list and concatenate later because of memory restrictions even tho I have 64 GB of RAM.

To avoid saving everything into memory, I'm streaming the data into a file using:

```
entidad_csv = folder_entidad / f"{entidad.name.lower()}.csv"
for f in tqdm(files):
    df = descomprime(f)
    df.to_csv(entidad_csv, index=False, mode="a", header=not entidad_csv.exists())
```

But I'm having problems when a column is missing in one of the files because it appends the rows as is. I don't know before hand which columns are present in each file so I need the merged file to have every column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use `os.system("cat filea.csv > fileb.csv")`?

Comment: Yeah but the rows will be miss aligned :(

Comment: Do all CSV files have a header row that matches the columns in each file?

Comment: Yes, every csv has a column header, a set of columns is the same for all files.

Comment: I'm confused. What does "a set of columns is the same for all files" mean? You said "a column is missing in one of the files", what about the header of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use the logic below that uses :

- [`Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) : to form a unique combination between the headers
- [`insert_line_front`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734140/16120011) : to replace/overwrite the header at each iteration
- [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) : to produce NaN values below the missing col(s)

```
output_file = Path("output_folder") / "merged.csv"

for file_path in tqdm(Path("input_files").glob("*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    if not output_file.exists():
        df.to_csv(output_file, index=False) # header=True
    else:
        with open(output_file, "r") as file:
            old_header = file.readline().strip()
        if old_header:
            new_header = pd.Index(old_header.split(",")).union(df.columns, sort=False)
            #https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734140/16120011 © Stephen Rauch
            insert_line_front(output_file, new_header.str.cat(sep=","))
            df.reindex(new_header, axis=1).to_csv(
                output_file, index=False, header=False, mode="a"
            )
```

Test/Output :

`file1.csv`:

```
col1
foo
bar
qux
```

`file2.csv`:

```
col3,col4
uu,3
ww,4
```

`file3.csv`:

```
col5,col2,col1
ii,5,baz
jj,6,qux
```

---

`merged.csv` (*in tabular format*) :

| col1 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo |  |  |  |  |
| bar |  |  |  |  |
| qux |  |  |  |  |
|  | uu | 3.0 |  |  |
|  | ww | 4.0 |  |  |
| baz |  |  | ii | 5.0 |
| qux |  |  | jj | 6.0 |

*Tree view :*

```
input_files
┣━━ file1.csv
┣━━ file1.csv
┗━━ file3.csv
output_folder
┗━━ merged.csv
```

Comment: Nice! logic is sound and this might be a solution but its giving me a UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4935: character maps to <undefined> that Im trying to figure out

Comment: In which line the error is thrown ? Anyways, you might play with the encodings to get the right one, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65596858/16120011) answer that addresses a similar error..

Comment: I figured it out. What if I want to avoid appending repeated rows?

Comment: I don't think this would be possible without reading the whole previous merged file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a list of columns based on files read and make it a blank dataframe with header only and then use the blank dataframe to concat with new csv file. It will make a new dataframe with all columns from files.