# What's the most optimal way to rewrite headers of a very big csv file?

Tags: python

I have many huge CSV files (2-4 GB), I just want to rewrite the headers of CSV files without loading the whole file.

What's the optimal way to do this? Headers on each file are different, just want to give header names as input parameter and join it with the body of the file.

Comment: Adding data to a file makes is necessary to re-write the file from there on. So if you add a header you have to read and write the whole file.

Comment: if new line with headers has the same size - the same number of bytes - then you can simply overwrite it in file. For shorter you could try to add spaces to make it the same size. But if it needs more bytes then you will have to create new file.

Comment: If you are going to use the csv in pandas later, you can simply change the headers of the loaded csv dataframe using pandas methods, rather than change the csv itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947384/4440387

Comment: I have done assumption, probably reading first line would be more optimized, that is why my question starts with "Is there" ? The problem is how quickly the process will work out, the fastest way to transform the header.

Comment: @DenisRasulev If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thanks for the feedback, next time will do. Upvoted your comment. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your csv is a line by line file (Obviously), the file object reader already has this option :

```
for line in open('your_really_very_so_big_file.csv'):
    process_data(line)
```

However this for read only, if you wanna write you have to read the whole stream.
However, one of the good tips for your case is a copy paste after editing, something like:

```
source.readline() 
destination.write(edited_line)
shutil.copyfileobj(source, destination)
```

**EDIT :**

Similar answer here: [shutil.copyfileobj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947384/14872512)

Doc: [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question which is *Is there a very optimal way __to rewrite headers__ of huge csv file*

Comment: So now you simply copied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947384/4440387)? What's `destination`?

Comment: The copy to a new file is better than reading/writing the whole stream in your code but still doesn't solve the problem of huge files(Sorry part of my answer wasn't loaded)

Comment: 1- Didn't see there was an already look alike answer
2- I 'm here just trying to help you with your problem 3- By destination i mean your destination csv file that you create

Comment: 1- this is not my question. 2- did you mean `destination.write(edited_line)`?

Comment: yes, i've edited it, thanks